# How have InputBox appear unless user entry is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA program which has user enter numbers or strings until they want to end the program, so they enter an empty string by hitting Enter without typing anything. *This is the goal.*

When I run this I get error:

> Compile error:
>
> Argument not optional

This is the code:

```
Sub enterinputs()
inputs = 1
Do While IsEmpty(inputs) = False
    inputs = InputBox("Enter names of inputs. Leave blank + Enter to stop.", title)
    Trim(InputBox.Value & inputs) = inputs
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `InputBox.Value` is inputs, but I don't think it would work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for ***False***:

```
Sub WhatIsTruth()
   Dim v As Variant
   v = True

   Do Until v = False
      v = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Value", Type:=1)
   Loop
End Sub
```

This will allow you to enter numbers to be processed as well as detect **cancel** or **x**.